# AWS CDK ignoring symbolic links when deploying

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I have a lerna project that includes a cdk module, which defines a stack with a lambda. The lambda  has a dependency on another  module in the monorepo. Dependencies are installed using lerna boostrap with hoisting.

The resulting dependency in the stack is a symbolic link to the monorepo's node_modules. When I deploy the stack, the dependency isnt bundled with the lambda. Is there a way to ask cdk to dereference/follow the link when deploying?

Comment: in case anyone is interested, I ended up dereferencing the links before deploying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AssetOptions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_s3_assets.AssetOptions.html) support following symlink, e.g.

```
    query_function = Function(self, 'QueryFunction',
        code=Code.from_asset(join(object_path(__class__), 'deploy/query_services'),
            follow_symlinks=SymlinkFollowMode.ALWAYS),
        handler='lambda_function.lambda_handler',
        runtime=Runtime.PYTHON_3_9,
        layers=[layer],
        log_retention=RetentionDays.TWO_WEEKS
    )
```

Comment: Im not in a position to test this currently, but looking at the documentation this seems the right answer